# Can struct timespec reusable for nanosleep?

Tags: c++, c, sleep

My program planning to looping for getting some element from the queue, however, keep looping might overhead CPU usage, I'm wonder to put a nanosleep with 1ms wait. Can I just make `struct timespec shared_time_wait;` on global, and reuse it?

```
struct timespec shared_time_wait;

void wait1ms()
{   
    nanosleep(&shared_time_wait, NULL);
}

void init() {
 unsigned int ms = 1;
 shared_time_wait.tv_sec = ms / (1000 * 1000);
 shared_time_wait.tv_nsec = (ms % (1000 * 1000)) * 1000;

 for(;;) {
  wait1ms();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 2 nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html):

```
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);
```

It's perfectly fine to reuse `req`, since it's declared as `const`. Since you aren't changing it yourself, and the `const`-ness of the function means it's not changing it either, no harm can come of reusing it. (The above wouldn't be true for `rem`, since it is written to, but you're not using that so you don't have to worry about it.)